# Selenium: Scrolling a scroll bar within browser window (not the browser scroll bar)

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to scroll within the browser window. Normally you would scroll the browser's scroll bar through:

```
browser.execute_script('window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight)')
```

But this is not what I am trying to do. In the image below you'll see the scroll bar that I am trying to scroll down through.

See red arrow for the scroll bar where I want to scroll:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Please read why a [screenshot of HTML or code or error is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Consider updating the Question with formatted text based relevant HTML, code trials and error stack trace.

Comment: Is this question solved? Even I am stuck with the same problem. I did not find a proper solution either with actions or Expected conditions

Answer (score 0):

You can use `move_to_element` from [ActionChains](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains). Locate the element you want to scroll to and `move_to_element` will scroll to it

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

element = driver.find_element(...)
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).perform()
```

Comment: How the element will be visible and able to be located only after I scroll down. I am not able to locate it even though all the elements in the custom scroll menu follows a pattern